# Falling into a logic error in EF

Tags: c#, entity-framework, asp.net-mvc-4, rss, logic

This could be a little complicated, well for me. It depends of the context, but here is what I have.

This all starts at the controller, I have an action to add feed, this call an action in a repository and the method in the repository is who really save the feed in the database.

**Controller.**

```
public ActionResult Create(Feed feed)
    {
        if (ModelState.IsValid)
        {
            feed.UserModelID = UserManager.GetInstance.Search(User.Identity.Name).UserModelID;
            if (FeedManager.GetInstance.Add(feed))
            {
                ViewBag.success = "success";
            }
            else
            {
                ViewBag.success = "error";
            }
        }
        return View(feed);
    }
```

The feed has a foreign key, in this case the user id (UserModelID), that I assign before calling the method in repository.

**Repository.**

```
public Boolean Add(Feed f)
    {
        if (GetLastestFeeds(f) != null)
        {
            f.Articles = GetLastestFeeds(f);
            Feeds.Add(f);
            Db.Feeds.Add(f);
            Db.SaveChanges();
            return true;
        }
        return false;
    }
```

**The feed model.**

```
public class Feed
{
    public Int32 FeedID { get; set; }

    [Required(ErrorMessage = "The name is required")]
    [StringLength(32, MinimumLength = 8, ErrorMessage = "The name must be at least 8 characters")]
    public String Name { get; set; }

    [Required(ErrorMessage = "The url is required")]
    [Url(ErrorMessage = "Invalid URL")]
    public String Url { get; set; }

    [Required(ErrorMessage = "A type must be selected")]
    public Boolean IsAtom { get; set; }

    public Byte[] Image { get; set; }
    public String ImageIcon { get; set; }
    public Int32 UserModelID { get; set; }

    public virtual ICollection<Article> Articles { get; set; }
}
```

The problem here is, when I refresh, for some reason the user doesn't have the reference to the new feed added. I put a break point in some part of my code, search for the user entity its feeds property is still null. I tried changing the logic, adding the feeds from the user, so I replaced this...

```
Db.Feeds.Add(f);
```

for this...

```
Db.Users.Where(u => u.UserModelID == feed.UserModelID).first().feeds.Add(feed);
```

It didn't work.

Comment: How do you "refresh", what *exactly* do you mean by that?

Comment: A new GET request to the page... because I'm not using ajax and partial updates, I have to refresh the page...

Comment: "The page" - the one showing the feed? How do you know "the user doesn't have the reference to the new feed added"?

Comment: When I refresh the page (the one that show the feeds) I call an action (that action search the user on the data base, take its feeds, and display them), in that action I put a break point in code, and see that the user that is returned has no feeds.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I still have to guess a couple of things, but apparently you have singleton manager objects, each having their own context instances. This is not recommended. In web applications you normally should have a context per request, no long-lived contexts.

You add the `Feed` to the `FeedManager` instance, but I think that you show the users from the `UserManager` instance. I also think that the line `Db.Users.Where(u => u.UserModelID == feed.UserModelID).first().feeds.Add(feed);` is executed in the `FeedManager` instance. The bottom line is, these instances know nothing of each other, so if you add feeds to one of them, they will not get added to the user in the other instance, unless you actively reload the user. But you don't seem to do that.

Whether my guesses are close or not, this can all be solved if you use context per request. Maybe you can achieve that by using new `Manager` objects per request, if that means that each new manager object also has a new context instance.

Comment: I have the solution thanks, It was really helpful and it will let me improve some things. You're right I'm getting users from UserManager, and I forgot to add the feed to the user located in that instance.

Comment: You're welcome. But that would be a short-term solution. I think you really have to bite the bullet and improve your overall architecture.

Comment: I should call a new instance of the db context in each method of the singleton repository, because I don't want interaction with in controller actions. I understood that, could it be?

Comment: That could be a first major improvement. But I'd also try to do away with these singletons, if possible...

Comment: Sure, I'll be searching for a better solution. Thanks again.